# Python plot long x-axis with scroll-bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

Note : I read about [slider](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html), but that seems to require updating the plot as slider moves.
My calculation will take some time if I am to `update` it with window of 100 entries each.
Therefore I'd like to do calculation once with a big chunk, and review the result.

I have a time series with thousands of entries.

At the moment I'm only able to visualize a small chunk of 100 entries each time, otherwise the plot will be cramped altogether.

Is there a way to, say, plot 1000 entries, but fit the current window to only 100 entries at a time to be visible ? A scrollbar on x-axis will slide the window to capture different 100-entries at one time.

Comment: It's already provided by the interactive backends: you could plot all values at once, set the xlim to say `(0,100)` and then use the `pan` tool button to scroll through the plot.

Comment: Could you point me to a working example ? I was not able to find an example on your **pan** tool. Most examples is about re-computing the plot as some actions happen, e.g. a slider moves. Thanks

Comment: see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/navigation_toolbar.html. You don't need to program anything, the pan tool is provided by matplotlib.